# Java SoundSystem error

Tags: java, audio, recording

I am trying to make a program that plays sound back to you. How I got the sound was I went to [this link](http://www.oddcast.com/home/demos/tts/tts_example.php) and I had it speak some words for about 9 seconds. While he was speaking, I was recording him with Audacity. It recorded him at 16-bit PCM, 48 khz and a stereo channel.

The code I use to play the sound is,

```
 public void playSound(String Path) {
      try {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Variables.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/project/resources/" + Path));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start(); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

and the error that pops up is at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BEcf.png) link.

I have stored the file in another package located at com.project.resources.
If you have any questions about this situation, let me know.

Comment: The class 'Variables' is the class I have that is attempting to run the sound.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/e5LyhuD.png that's the format in which I record the audio. Also, the saved file is a .wav file type

Comment: Have you considered encoding your sound file to a different format to test if it is your code that is the problem, or Java actually does not support that format as reported

Comment: Something is odd, the exception says "8 bytes/frame", which would mean 32 bit samples.

Comment: @mckuok I have tried using mp3, but that is it. mp3 did not work either, saying that java did not support that file format.

Comment: I don't really know much in the audio file areas, but when I went to the Properties of the .wav file, it said this: https://i.imgur.com/h5QsQ45.png So it could possibly be that Audacity is screwing up the bitrate